# ¿Qué tipo de palabra es «alto»?

Tags: definiciones, categorías-gramaticales

En las intersecciones, es común ver una señal roja y octagonal que dice *"alto"*, el mismo tipo de señal que en inglés dice *stop*.

En inglés, *stop* es un verbo imperativo, pero no creo que haya un verbo en español como *"altar"*, y *"alto"*; no parece una forma imperativa.

¿Qué significa *"alto"* en este contexto, y por qué la señal no dice *"pare"*?

Comment: I've been told the English "Halt!" and the Spanish *¡Alto!* have the same origin.

Comment: alto in mexico means someone tall  too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the definition in [RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?LEMA=alto)

> **alto**.
>
> 1. **interj**. U. para ordenar a alguien que se detenga o que suspenda lo que está haciendo.

So it is an **interjection** which means "stop". It's like an order to stop.

> El policía dijo: ¡Alto!

Of course the person who created the signal could have written "**pare**" instead and people would stop, though "alto" usually is said by people who can command you to do something and you can't refuse (like policemen); "Pare" could be used by any person.

Indeed in Spain those signals use the English word "**Stop**" instead of "Alto".

Answer (score 3):

In some Latin American countries `Stop` signs say `Pare` and not `Alto`; however, [RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=alto) shows that `Alto` comes from the German `Halten` (Detener); therefore, it's an imperative word used in this context.

Comment: Where do the signs say *Pare* instead of *Alto*? I've only seen *Alto* on signs in Mexico and Nicaragua.

Comment: @jrdioko In Colombia, Argentina, Chile and the Dominican Republic at least in some regions. I've been to Mexico several times but I don't remember exactly whether the sign says `Pare` or `Alto`. Check this out: http://www2.geog.okstate.edu/users/lightfoot/stop.html I ran an image Google search for "señal de pare" and found several images that say `Pare`.

Comment: Perhaps it's true of most of *South America* rather than most of *Latin America*?

Comment: @hippietrail perhaps, but the Dominican Republic is not in South America. Perhaps *in some* Latin American countries is more appropriate. I will amend.

Comment: Check the [Wikipedia article on Stop signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_sign) for some history, variations and more. It says that *PARE* is used in Argentina, Bolivia, Brazil, Chile, Colombia, Cuba, Dominican Republic, Ecuador, Paraguay, Peru, Puerto Rico, Uruguay and Venezuela and *ALTO* is used in Mexico and Central American countries.